# R: How to change all values with negative condition

Tags: r, loops, conditional-statements

I have this data frame

```
Data structure(list(ID = 1:3, WEEK1 = c(1L, "A", 1.23), WEEK2 = c(1L, "AL", 1.68), WEEK3 = c("L", 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

DF ID  WEEK1    WEEK2   WEEK3
   1   1        A       1.23
   2   1        AL      1.68 
   3   L        1       2
```

There is lot of random strings in the data frame.
I would like to have negative conditional loop that change all values that not 1 to 0.

Like in data frame

```
DF ID  WEEK1    WEEK2   WEEK3
   1   1        O       O
   2   1        O       O 
   3   O        1       O
```

This can change only known strings, but is it possible to change it to negative condition?

```
df %>% mutate(across(matches("WEEK"), chartr, old = '123', new =  'ABC'))
```

Comment: You could just do `Data[,-1][Data[,-1]!="1"] <- "0"`

Comment: Thank you, that worked pretty well. But its pity that I am not able to select columns 2:3 (just "week" columns).

Comment: Not sure why you could not just select columns 2:3? Like `Data[,2:3][Data[,2:3]!="1"] <- "0"` (lthough in your example columns 2:4 are "week" columns); you could also grep "WEEK" to subset: `Data[,grep("WEEK", colnames(Data))][Data[,grep("WEEK", colnames(Data))]!="1"] <- "0"`

Comment: Thank you. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest next approach. You have to notice that all values in your dataframe are character strings:

```
#Data
Data <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, WEEK1 = c("1", "A", "1.23"), WEEK2 = c("1", 
"AL", "1.68"), WEEK3 = c("L", "1", "2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

The code:

```
#Loop
for(i in 2:dim(Data)[2])
{
  Data[,i]<-ifelse(Data[,i]!='1',0,Data[,i])
}
```

Output:

```
  ID WEEK1 WEEK2 WEEK3
1  1     1     1     0
2  2     0     0     1
3  3     0     0     0
```